# problem with put where in query(rownum)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, where-clause

i use of "codeigniter" and `rownum` query, i want put `WHERE` in inside query but have following error. how is it?

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE '*' = '0' ) t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r' at line 7
>
> SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* FROM ( SELECT * FROM
>   hotel_submits ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0, 6 WHERE * = 1 ) t, (SELECT
>   @rownum:=0) r
>
> Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\hdr\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

```
$this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM hasana_you
        ORDER BY id desc
        LIMIT $offset, $coun_page
        WHERE * = 1 //or $id instead 1
    ) t,
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) r");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` always comes before `LIMIT` and `ORDER`:

**EDITED PER DISCUSSION**

```
SELECT 
    @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, 
    t.*
FROM (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            hasana_you
        WHERE 
            column_a = 1 OR 
            column_b = 1 OR
            column_c = 1 OR
            column_d = 1 
        ORDER BY 
            id desc
        LIMIT 
            $offset, $count_page
) AS t
```

There are other issues that I see with this query (seems overly complex, may not need the subquery), but without your db structure I could not presume to correct it. However, the stated order of keywords stands as the primary concern.

Check out these tutorial articles on the various aspects of SQL syntax and usage: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlwhere.php

Comment: Because, again, there are other concerns with the query that I cannot address without knowledge of your database structure. I can tell you that `WHERE * = 1` is not valid. I have no idea what you're after there. What is the intention of that `WHERE` clause?

Comment: i want search in all columns on database: `* = all`. how it this? [search in all columns value `1`]

Comment: If you want to search all ROWS of the database, simply remove the `WHERE` clause all together. If you are looking to match any COLUMN to 1, you will have to list all the columns as separate clauses separated by the `OR` operator. SQL is designed to work with an unspecified number of rows and a known quantity of columns. See edited answer.

Comment: The number of columns is much, Another solution is to stop writing all the columns?

Comment: As I said, it depends on what you are trying to match. If you simply want all rows returned, do away with the `WHERE` clause. If you want to match columns against a value, you have no choice but to list the columns in your query.

Comment: how change this query `SELECT * FROM hasana_you WHERE * LIKE '%1%'` to my query(rownum)?

Comment: SELECT * FROM hasana_you WHERE column_1 LIKE '%1%' OR column_2 LIKE '%1%' OR column_3 LIKE '%1%'

Comment: no error but where or don't work. see: `$this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
     FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM hasana_you
  WHERE 
      name = '$find' OR 
      star = '$find' OR
      address = '$find' OR
      number_phone = '$find' OR 
      type = '$find' OR
      service = '$find' OR
      units = '$find' OR
      useradmin = '$find' OR 
      date = '$find'
  ORDER BY id desc
  LIMIT $offset, $coun_page     
     ) t,
     (SELECT @rownum:=0) r");`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$id= 1;
$f= $this->db->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name,
    \" like '%$id%' OR \" SEPARATOR '') AS str 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name='hasana_you'");
$f1= $f->row();
$filter= substr($f1->str,0,-4);
```

**Edited:**

```
$x= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r,
(SELECT *
    FROM hasana_you
    WHERE $filter
    ORDER BY id desc
) t) x
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT $offset, $count_page");
```

It's hard to know where you want the filter... can also be:

```
$x= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r,
(SELECT *
    FROM hasana_you
    ORDER BY id desc
) t) x
WHERE $filter
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT $offset, $count_page");
```

Comment: this have error, and don't work. an error like error first post

Comment: I would think that these questions are giving you partial solutions that you implemented in the code... Try now